# Jenkins slaves are disconnecting and builds are failing with Unexpected termination of the channel

Tags: git, jenkins

Suddenly we are experiencing the Jenkins build failures with the following message.

I checked the connectivity between salves and master seems fine and no packet loss observed. also no change. May I know what could be the cause. all slaves are mac pro servers.
Git Path is updated in node configuration **/usr/loal/bin** and all are **ssh** clients.

`````
FATAL: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2735)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3210)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:895)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:357)
 at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
 at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:142)
 at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:128)
 at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
 at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:61)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
 at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:75)
Also: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to salve1
 at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
 at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:199)
 at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor306.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.execute(Unknown Source)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1221)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1299)
 at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1204)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:636)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:508)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException
 at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:345)
 at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:1085)
 at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:89)````
`````